# Code working in Chrome but not in Firefox

Tags: php

The following code works in Chrome. But in Firefox the submit step is not working

```
<?php
if(!isset($_POST['submit'])){


?>
<form action="" method="post">
<b>ID:</b>
<input name="std_no" type="text" />
<input type="image" width="100" value="submit" name="submit" id="submit" src="images/butup.gif" alt="submit Button">
</form>

<?php 
} 
else {
    $id=$_POST['std_no'];
    echo $id;
    }

?>
```

Comment: Your form action is empty.  Try removing the attribute completely, rather than passing an empty value.

Comment: @Brad
Even remove it not working friend :(

Comment: @Brad The action attribute is required (at least in HTML 4 -- I'm assuming it is in other versions too).

Comment: @Corbin, It is not required in HTML5, and since he didn't specify the name of his script, I'm trying to help him debug the situation.  I agree, valid HTML is important, but this question is fairly hopeless without more information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that an image submit doesn't send the name "submit" it sends "submit_x" and "submit_y"

So you should check for

```
if (isset($_POST['submit_x']))...
```

EDIT: I've done a little more testing on this and it appears in Firefox (16) and IE(7, 8, 9) only the x and y get sent whereas in Chrome (23) and Safari (5.1) it also send the name too along with x and y.

So the safest way is to check for the value is : `isset($_POST['name_x'])`

Comment: No problem champ, for future reference you can do a `print_r($_POST);` to see what values are actually being sent by a form.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
if(!isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $id=$_POST['std_no']; // put it here so whenever you click submit button
        echo $id; // $_POST is trigger

?>
<form action="/**input action**/" method="post">
<b>ID:</b>
<input name="std_no" type="text" />
<input type="image" width="100" value="submit" name="submit" id="submit" src="images/butup.gif" alt="submit Button">
</form>
```

you should input in `action=""; // the php page of your code or the page where you want to get the data sample page.php`

or try this

```
<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?> // put in action
```