# Call bootstrap modal show event with php

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I want to call `modal('show')` event with php code. How can I do this? I tried the following:

```
if(isset($_POST['Edit'])){
echo "<script> $('#Modal').modal('show') </script>";}
```

I run this code, but `echo "<script> $('#Modal').modal('show') </script>";` doesnt work. How can I show modal  when image input is clicked? I don't want to call with image onlick.

Input:

```
<input type="image" src="image.png" name="Edit" value="Edit" alt="Edit" />
```

Modal:

```
<div class="modal hide fade" id="Modal" >
     <form method="post">
          <div class="modal-header">
               <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" style="margin-top:-10px">×</button>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
               <textarea id="text" name="text">Test</textarea>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
          </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Make sure you are echo'ing your script after jquery and bootstrap.js have been loaded

Comment: Also make sure there is a form surrounding the image input with its method set to post

Comment: And one last comment, some browsers (IE, FireFox) don't receive the name on an image input (they receive the x, y coordinates of where it was clicked [see this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13539986/1207346)), might want to try `$_POST['Edit_x']` in your isset

Comment: When I use image input onlick, it works. I think .js have been loaded.

Comment: I am sure post is ok. I think it is php and js code problem, not ie or anything.

Answer (score 14):

Set the document.ready function as shown below:

```
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#Modal').modal('show');
});
</script>";
```

On a side note, this work around is also great if you have a modal login form and need to alert the user on submit (or $_POST) for any submission errors in a seperate modal.

Answer (score 1):

You can use jquery fadeIn function to show model

```
$('#Modal').modal('show');
```

Change to

```
$('#Modal').fadeIn('show');
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: check if(isset($_POST['Edit'])){ echo "hello"; } , its echo'ing or not ?

Comment: Check: is bootstrap.js loaded?